# Downloading Specific Artifacts with Different Job IDs in GitLab

Tags: curl, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am utilizing the artifact download feature in GitLab by using the following command:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${TOKEN}" -o MANO_ISO.ISO "https://domain.xx/api/v4/projects/50/jobs/artifacts/dev/raw/build/image.iso?job=job_build"
```

This command successfully downloads the artifact from the specified job, but I am now interested in understanding how to download a specific artifact from the same job name but with a different job ID.

I tried to add in link jobs id like this:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${TOKEN}" -o MANO_ISO.ISO "https://domain.xx/api/v4/projects/50/jobs/$jobs_id/artifacts/dev/raw/build/image.iso?job=job_build""
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first API downloads the `latest(successful) job artifiact with the given job name`, instead of a specific job(with a job id)

Coming to you question

To download an artifact with a specific job ID `you should only pass in the project id and job id(not the job name)`

In your case the curl should look something like this

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${TOKEN}" -o MANO_ISO.ISO "https://domain.xx/api/v4/projects/50/jobs/$jobs_id/artifacts/dev/raw/build/image.iso"
```

Comment: Idk its related to gitlab istself or its curl problems... but it doesnt work.. i get error:

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     2    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

Comment: I am able to download using curl this way (here is a sample which works for me)   
curl --location --output xyz.yaml --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $MY_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<my project id>/jobs/<my jobid>/artifacts/folder1/folder2/xyz.yaml". As long as the job id is correct and the job has the specified artifact, it should work. So please check on these points.

Comment: it worked, error was because of /dev/raw when using job id its necessary to add branch name , thank you

Answer (score 0):

The command you provided seems to have an issue with the use of variable $jobs_id.
Try This link :

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${TOKEN}" -o MANO_ISO.ISO "https://domain.xx/api/v4/projects/50/jobs/${jobs_id}/artifacts/dev/raw/build/image.iso?job=job_build"
```

Comment: I use directly id number like this /jobs/231, its just example :)